# Why would i get a duplicate write error of auto-generated primary key?

Tags: sql-server-2005, primary-key

Hi I'm not a DBA so forgive my ignorance. I don't have access to administrator tools etc. However, I do know that we have a live server which is approaching capacity ie 80%-90% full perhaps.

What is happening is that our web-application has started not writing certain records and it appears as though SQLServer is attempting to write a duplicate primary key in certain tables. I don't understand this and as this is an auto-generated column it is completely out of our control.

Is this a possible symptom of the server getting too full? Surely a DBMS should manage this kind of thing safely?

Answer (score 4):

I think this could happen only if manual intervention was done to that primary key. It's possible to manually insert data in the identity column only if option "set identity_insert table_name on" was used, that way you can generate PK errors.
But better check exactly if the PK is only that identity column, and, if yes, if this option is used in any of the stored procedures or scripts that you use.

SQL Server alone would not have any reason to not treat correctly these columns.

Answer (score 1):

There could be probably two reasons,

1. The data type specified for the auto_increment column has reached its limit, for example if you have a TINYINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT column, this column would support a maximum value of 255, say you have already reached the value of 255, then inserting any further row would generate a value of 256 which will be truncated to 255 and then because that value is already present in the table, MySQL will throw a duplicate key error.
2. You are manually trying to insert a value in the AUTO_INCREMENT column that is already present in there,.

Answer (score -2):

It could be quite possible that you are using GUID's, which are not guaranteed to be unique. Since you mention that you are getting 'full', I am assuming that you have inserted many GUIDs so far and that every now and then the system happens to generate a GUID that is already in use.

If you have a specific error message to share, that would be helpful.

For more information check out Kimberly Tripp's blog posts at http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/Indexes.aspx